# Tried to import Mitre 2020 policy but failed

Tags: deepsecurity

I tried to import Mitre 2020 policies specified in this link but always failed:
https://github.com/trendmicro/c1ws-mitre-policy/tree/main/2020

I am using C1WS and go to Policies, Export from File.
The error mentions that the format is not valid, but the xml seems to be successfully downloaded.
How should I troubleshoot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to **import** a policy, correct? If that's the case, you're going to want to select `New` on the Policy screen, then `Import From File...`:

[image: A drop down showing New Policy and Import From File]

You should then be able to select the policy you downloaded from GitHub in the file picker and set its inheritance level.

Also, I know this goes without saying, but make sure you're downloading the correct version -- either Linux or Windows.